# How to set Clang-Format Style Options to keep no line break before catch?

Tags: c++, formatting, clang, clang-format

So currently I use next style:

```
{ 
  BasedOnStyle: "LLVM", 
  IndentWidth: 4,   
  UseTab: false, 
  ColumnLimit: 150, 
  Standard: "Cpp11",
  BreakBeforeBraces: "Attach",  
  BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: false,    
  AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true, 
  AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false,
  AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, 
  AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true, 
  SpacesInParentheses: true,    
  SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1, 
  SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false,
  SpaceAfterControlStatementKeyword: true, 
  PointerBindsToType: true, 
  MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1,
  IndentFunctionDeclarationAfterType: true, 
  IndentCaseLabels: true,
  ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: true, 
  DerivePointerBinding: true, 
  Cpp11BracedListStyle: false, 
  ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true,
  BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true
}
```

and get

```
try {
}
 catch ( ... ) {
}
```

While I want to get

```
try {
} catch ( ... ) {
}
```

Can any one say which [Clang-Format Style Option](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) is responsible for such behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

`BreakBeforeBraces` should, as I understand it, affect the behavior you are concerned with. `Attach` looks like the correct option from it description [on the style options page that you referenced](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html). The only reason that I can see for it not working is that `BreakBeforeBraces` expects a `BraceBreakingStyle` enum. Try it without the making `Attach` a string.

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
```

or

```
BreakBeforeBraces: BS_Attach
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for try-catch-blocks has only been added recently. If you update to a current version, this should be fixed.